# What is wrong with my drawImage function?

Tags: javascript

I cant seem to get my drawimage function to work on my canvas. I tried using the onload method I tried using the file on the application. Nothing seems to work, however. All I want to do is print the image from the url into my canvas.

Comment: You should provide some code examples and specify what you have tried so far

Comment: This is my full file. https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lichterman-klp4f?file=/game.js

Answer (score 2):

Change line 5 to `let image = document.createElement("img");`

When drawing images to a canvas you must provide an image element, created with document.createElement or stored in your index.html